# Very simple masking

Tags: c, logic, bit-manipulation

In 3 operations how can I turn a byte into a 32 bit int that matches this:

0x1fffe

I can only explicitly access a byte at a time thus I start with 0xFF and then shift it.

I can do it using 4 operations but I cant find a way to eliminate one operation.

```
    int mask2 = 0xFF << 8;
    mask2 = mask2 | 0xFE;
    mask2 = mask2 + mask2;
    mask2 = mask2 | 0x02;
```

Any ideas?

In other words, I need a mask, 0x1FFFE to be made in 3 operations **while only accessing a byte at a time** like the example.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve (in particular, your constraints), I see *three* bytes being used here, not counting the other two integer literals...

Comment: I turn a byte, 0xFF into a 32 bit int, 0x001FFFFE in 4 operators. How can I do it in 3 using the same restrictions?

Comment: You are using 3 different bytes as operands... `0xff`, `0xfe`, `0x02`.

Comment: what operations are you restricted to?  i.e., why can't you just do `(byte & 0x0) | 0x1fffe`  (2 bitwise operations)

Comment: How about `((0xff) & 0) | 0x1ffffe`?  Probably cheating right?

Comment: I can only access a byte explicitly so I wont be able to use 0x1fffe.

Comment: Perhaps make use of the signing of the int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want... you start with *one single* byte value (0xff), and you work on it with 3 *bitwise* operations, obtaining 0x1fffe.

```
int in = 0xff;
int out = in<<9 | in<<1;
```

Comment: Duh! Thank you that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 2):

shift, add, shift, that's three operations, right?

`((0xff << 8) + 0xff) << 1`

Comment: +1, but I'd change that `+` with a `|` to make it use only bitwise operations.

Answer (score 1):

with two operations:

```
res = (1 << 17) - 2
```

Comment: hehe yes, just realized that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int mask2 = 0xFF;
mask2 |= mask2 << 8;
mask2 += mask2;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
((~0xffU) >> 11) - 1
```

This assumes 32-bit integers...

Maybe that's better expressed as:

```
uint32_t x = 0xff;

x = ~x;
x >>= 11;
x -= 1;
```

Comment: @Omri - Yeah, I was realizing as I wrote it out that my first example assumes `int` is 32-bit.  It also has issues due to `0xff` being signed.  I fixed it, and provided an example that explicitly used `uint32_t`.